# My string and a variable won't work together in this tkinter function?

Tags: python, tkinter

[Here's an image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlfqM.png)

[Here is a glimpse into the files being used. The image I'm trying to put as my background is in 'stuff'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0r0r.png)

I have a variable called 'location'. This gets the location the python file is in. And I have a string, called '/Stuff'. Put together makes 'C:\users\username\desktop\creative projects\coding\python\Simplistic_Calculator\Stuff\Image', but when I run the code, I get this error, because the function I'm using 'tkinter.image(image.open())', doesnt support a string and a variable. Any ideas? Help would be appreciated :)

Here's My Code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import Image
from getpass import *
import sys
import pathlib
import pynput

user = getuser()
location = pathlib.Path().absolute()

background = location

# delete this, once you have finished making settings.
def settings_sorry():
    messagebox.showinfo("Yeah, sorry", "Settings is not avaiable at the moment, sorry.")

#-----------------------------------------
root = Tk()
root.title("Simplistic Calculator - 0.01")

root.configure(bg="white")

Tk_background = PhotoImage(location + "Stuff/Sparks_Background")
Tk_backgroundLabel = Label(root, Image=Tk_background)
# Placing the image down
Tk_backgroundLabel.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

# Below code was grabbed off the internet: https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/66181/center-a-tkinter-window
def center_window(w=300, h=200):
    # get screen width and height
    ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = root.winfo_screenheight()
    # calculate position x, y
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)    
    y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

# The numbers at the end are the size of the window.
center_window(440, 200)

#-----------------------------------------
Welcome = Label(root, text="Welcome To Simplistick Calculator. Type in the box to begin")
Tip = Label(root, text="You can use your computer's keyboard to type in the numbers and symbols", fg="#9e9e9e")

# Make a settings window after you finish the calculator functions and maybe make an auto update thing that can detect new updates.
settings_open = Button(root, text="Settings", command=settings_sorry)

settings_open.configure(bg="white")
Welcome.configure(bg="white")
Tip.configure(bg="white")

# how to get settings_open to the bottom left?
settings_open.grid(row=4, column=0)
Welcome.grid(row=0, column=0)
Tip.grid(row=1, column=0)

# Answer button and input box. Also some of the math.
number_input = Entry(root)

# If 'ENTER' is pressed, press 'Answer' button. This code here please.

def math():
    numbers = (number_input).get()

    print(numbers)

answer_button = Button(root, text="Answer", width=16, command=math)
number_input.grid()
answer_button.grid()

number_input.place(x=150, y=80)
answer_button.place(x=150, y=120)

number_input.configure(bg="#f7f7f7")
answer_button.configure(bg="#f7f7f7")
# Now for the actual coding. Making all the stuff above do something.


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use `PhotoImage(file=location.joinpath("Stuff/Sparks_Background"))` or `PhotoImage(file=location/"Stuff/Sparks_Background")` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use '+' operator on two different data types. Your variable 'location' is not a string, it's a WindowsPath variable. You can try wrapping it with str() so that it would look like this:

```
Tk_background = PhotoImage(str(location) + "Stuff/Sparks_Background")
```

Comment: Kubaki18 - Thank you, I think it worked. This might seem selfish, but could you help me with the next error? If so, it now says "unknown option "-Image"" https://imgur.com/a/4WFhqD4

Comment: @crjase Did you print the output of `str(location)`?  As it may not include the trailing `/`, so `str(location) + "Stuff/Sparks_Background"` may not be a valid path.  For your another error, `Image=...` should be `image=...`.

Comment: @acw1668 It works, thank you. You and the other person are complete legends!